# How to create an API endpoint without a model in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I understand we can create remote methods on models which will expose an endpoint. However, is there a way to expose an endpoint without a model?

For example, if I want to create an endpoint checks the version of a native app. I don't need a model to back this endpoint. The endpoint would simply check the passed in version and respond.

Does this construct exist within Loopback?  Or does it need to be done within the context of Express?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use express routes as shown in [Loopback's Getting Started example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started/blob/master/server/boot/routes.js).

Comment: Right, so you have to dip into Express. Thanks.

Comment: A complete guide in the Loopback v3 docs: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Add-a-custom-Express-route.html